# How to connect Spark with Power-BI?

Tags: pyspark

How can I connect Spark with Power-BI? So that I can fetch all data directly from Spark using Python. I have seen several posts but that's not meet my requirements.

Comment: Why do those posts not meet your requirements? What are your requirements?

Comment: only want to connect spark to power-bi and fetch data directly from spark. My question is how to do that? I have seen several posts but that's not meet my requirements. @EdgarR.Mondragón